# Multiple binding for textbox

Tags: wpf

I have a TextBox which is bound to a chart control (3rd party WPF control).

When I hover over the chart, the textbox show chart X axis value.

Now I have another chart. I want to bind the same textbox with this chart so that when I hover on any of the chart, the data from respective is shown in textbox.

I have gone through multiple bindings in WPF, but not sure if that can be used in my scenario.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have you chart control (whatever it is), so I can only simulate what is going on.

In this example I have two sliders each are bound to the SAME textbox, but only to push values it, I believe this `OneWayToSource` is what you need.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"

    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">


<StackPanel>
    <Slider Value="{Binding ElementName=Output, Path=Text, Mode=OneWayToSource}"/>
    <Slider Value="{Binding ElementName=Output, Path=Text, Mode=OneWayToSource}"/>
    <TextBlock Name="Output"/>
</StackPanel>
</Window>
```